# Plot two lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have file with two columns like:

```
1.2, 3.4
5.6, 7.8
...
```

I want gnuplot to plot both columns in one coordinate system like it would, if there was only one column. Meaning: X-axis shows the line numbers, y-axis the values.

Example: The first two points of the two lines are `(0, 1.2)`and `(0, 3.4)`; the second points `(1, 5.6)` and `(1, 7.8)`.

I do not want the two columns being treated as x and y values, like it would if just go for `plot "data.txt"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the zero pseudo column which holds the current sample number. From `help pseudocolumns`:

```
column(0)
    The sequential order of each point within a data set.
    The counter starts at 0 and is reset by two sequential blank
```

For example:

```
plot 'data.txt' using 0:1, '' using 0:2
```

The empty `''` uses the same data-source as the previous plot.

Comment: you might want to explain the pseudo-column `0` as well.  That's just as magical as the pseudo-file `''` in my opinion :) -- But good answer, +1 from me

Comment: @mgilson: Good point thanks. I've added explanation and reference to the help.